# Solving an ordinary differential equation nonlinear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following

$$ y' = \frac{ xy }{x^2 + y^2} $$

My approach would be to rewrite this in terms of $x$

$$ x' = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} $$

And then let $u = \frac{y}{x} \implies u' = \frac{x + y x'}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{u}{x} x' = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{u}{x} \left( \frac{1}{u} + u\right)$. Therfore,

$$ u' = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{u^2}{x} = \frac{2 + u^2}{x}$$

Thus,

$$ \int \frac{ d u}{2 + u^2} = \int \frac{ dx}{x} \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \arctan (u/ \sqrt{2}) = \ln |x| + C$$

So general solution ( with $u = y/x$) is

$$ \boxed{  \arctan \left( \frac{y}{x \sqrt{2}} \right) = \sqrt{2} \ln |x| + \sqrt{2} +C }$$

is this sufficient? is  there an easier way to solve this ODE?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $y = v x \implies y' = v + x v'$. Substitute and solve.

Comment: This isn't math 266A is it? They probably want you to use the fact that this equation is scale invariant.

Answer (score 1):

$$y' = \frac{ xy }{x^2 + y^2}=\frac{\frac{y}{x}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}$$
let $y=ux$ 
$$y'=u+xu'$$
so
$$u+xu'=\frac{u}{1+u^2}$$
$$xu'=\frac{-u^3}{1+u^2}$$
$$-\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{u^2+1}{u^3}du$$
$$-\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{1}{u}du+\frac{1}{u^3}du$$

Answer (score 0):

This belongs to the class of homogeneous differential equations of order 0, that is, it satisfies $f(\lambda x, \lambda y) =  f(x,y)$. One way to solve such a equation is to write the differential equation in the form: $y' = f(\frac{y}{x})$ and make the substitution $v=\frac{y}{x}$.